# Restoring a running database in a different name in same server in SQL Server 2012 using Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, restore

I have SQL Server 2012 (64-bit) (MSSQL11)
running on Windows 2012 R2 (64-bit) (NT 6.3)
with .NET framework 4.0.

It has a database called db_X and since this is a live production database it is always running and stopping it is not an option.

This is the only SQL Server database server that I practically have.

I want to take a backup (i.e. a full backup) of db_X (which I know how to do) and restore that backup (that .bak file) under a different name (say db_Y) in the same SQL Server database server.

I created a new database called db_Y, then right clicked db_Y then went to Tasks --> Restore --> Database...

Then I gave the path to that .bak file (as source) and tried to restore it by giving db_Y as destination (with the option - overwrite the existing database i.e. WITH REPLACE)

But this is not working. It is giving an error.

It says restore of database db_Y failed. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The file C:...\db_X1.mdf cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database db_X. Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.

But I still believe that this can be done using the Management Studio. Or at least using a script. (as this is a common requirement.)

Why is it trying to restore on db_X, when I have clearly given db_Y as my destination? Isn't this a bit scary as db_X is my live database (because I might lose some data)?

How is it possible to (have a copy of an existing and running database under a different name in SQL Server or in other words) restore a backup of an existing and running database with a different name in SQL Server 2012?

I am grateful if someone could kindly explain how this can be done using the Management Studio or at least using a script.

Answer (score 1):

When you are restoring the database, you need to rename the database to something other than the name of the original:
[image]

And then click the Files section and makes sure the file names are different than the original database:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and the answer. You say "When you are restoring the database, you need to rename the database to something other than the name of the original" How can I do this? I renamed the backup file as db_Y.bak but when I gave db_Y.bak as my source it shows db_X (and not db_Y) as the name of the database (probably because inside the file db_Y.bak, it is very likely that it has been mentioned that this file contains the backup of a database called db_X) Isn't the name of the database (under the source) is automatically selected by SSMS and I cannot change it?

Comment: On that first screenshot, the highlighted field is what the restored database will be called. You want something different in there than what the original database was called.